# Crear .jar de maven con javaFX da error **no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en prueba-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Tags: java, javafx, maven, compilar, jar

Crea un Maven con el IDE eclipse 2019-12 con archetype `javafx-archetype-fxml` siguiendo los pasos de https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ en los pasos de `JavaFX and Eclipse` apartado `Non-modular with Maven`.
Hasta ahi todo bien, pero al crear el .jar con el install, al intentar ejecutar el proyecto me sale el error:
[image: Output]

> Codigo en el POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>probando</groupId>
    <artifactId>prueba</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>probando.prueba.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

El POM contiene el por defecto que te da el archetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre al final un video que me resolvia el problema, aparte de crear un ejecutable para el programa. 
[Video mencionado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG8YCLYccVo)

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la manera de que te ejecute con el comando `mvn clean javafx:run` pero aun asi, no he encontrado la forma de ponerlo dentro del POM para que pueda ejecutar el .jar directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que el JAR que se genera Maven no incluye, por defecto, la entrada correspondiente a la clase que contiene el método `main(String[])` en el manifiesto, por lo que al intentar ejecutar el archivo la JVM no sabe que clase quieres usar como punto de entrada (recuerda que puedes tener N clases que contengan un método `main(String[])`).

La solución es simple. Agrega el plugin `maven-jar-plugin` que te permite indicar cual es la clase "main" de tu JAR.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>prueba.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Notar que donde dice `prueba.Main` `prueba` representa el paquete donde se encuentra tu clase "main" y `Main` es el nombre de dicha clase.

Comment: Esa parte resolvia uno de los problemas, pero aun asi, no me encontraba las librerias, aun asi muchas gracias. si te interesa encontre un video que tiene todo para la ejecucion

Comment: Claro, porque tienes que descargar todas la dependencias y luego referenciarlas igualmente en el MANIFEST o con el comando de ejecución de la aplicación

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso me funcionó muy bien con el siguiente codigo en el pom.xml ademas de que con esto pude crear con todo y dependencias para solo ejecutar el .jar

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest><!-- Seespecifica el directorio de la clase principal Main -->
                        <mainClass>com.organizacion.miClasePrincipal</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>        
</build>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).